# FatalExecutionEngineError when calling function from another assembly

Tags: c#, debugging, clr

My question is why the described solution to problem below works.
Intro: I have a small c++ server application, that does its business logic in c#. I use DllExport for the (reverse) pinvoke. All is peachy, everything is fast, stable, no leaks or any issue.
C# is composed of several assemblies(all is 4.7.2, x64 as is native), but i keep exports only in one.

Problem: One part of development led me to call a trivial utility public static function from another assembly that only contains a single file with single static class with about 15 helper functions and a single interface

```
public interface ISerializable
        {
            BinaryWriter  serial(BinaryWriter w);
            //ISerializable serial(BinaryReader w);//itself
        }
```

When debugger hits the function, it immediately threw null pointer exception and when i hit continue, it threw FatalExecutionEngineError. The exception happens as the function is called, before anything else happens. When looking at assembly debugger, it happens on the CALL instruction. Again, there were no stack issues or anything untoward.

Things i tried:
Being paranoid about eliminating mistakes on my part, i created an clean call pinvoke that internally only called a simple test function doing nothing from the same class.
It crashed immediately.
When i moved this test function to new static class in the same assembly, it worked....

What worked: Out of desperation, i moved the interface to a separate static class and everything started to work.

Obviously, this is a cargo cult coding and i would like to understand how to debug the issue. How in theory could the dllexport/pinvoke cause this this bug? Anyone seen anything similar?

Comment: FEEE is almost always caused by a memory corruption problem.  Most typically detected during a garbage collection.  The cargo cult is that you'll lower the odds to trigger a collection when you use a "static class".  The primary motivation behind managed code is to avoid the universal problem of memory corruption.  But that guarantee isn't worth a dime when you have a bunch of native C++ code, it rarely needs a lot of help to corrupt memory.

Comment: I had a lot of sad and true empirical experience of what you say with pinvoke so i am aware of the usual culprits. I went to great length to actually do nothing prior to execution of the given managed code within native binary.

Comment: This is not pinvoke, that's designed to have managed code run native code.  You are going the other way around, that's riskier.  Especially so with this utility, of the three possible ways to do this it is the worst since it doesn't protect you at all from getting the native function pointer declaration wrong.  Just show evidence of the "great length" and post repro code.

Comment: Again you say it is probably memory issue. Why should it be, when this only manifests when i am calling trivial function from trivial function and only when this function is within the same class as a random unrelated interface.